Merge static libraries and its dependencies using CMake
I have a static library built using CMake. This library depends on several others and to ease the work to another team we are merging all static libraries into one before shipping the product to them (for some reasons it has been decided to ship our product as a static library and not a dynamic one and I can't change that).
As of today we manually collected the list of dependencies and wrote a script that invokes the archiver, however I thought this could be done automatically by cmake and I gave it a try.
I managed to extract the list of dependencies modifying this answer, but I'm not quite sure how to turn that into a list of paths I can provide to ar/libtool.
Here's the code for my last attempt. From the output it looks like all the arguments are passed to libtool as a unique quoted string.
function(get_dependencies TARGET)
    get_target_property(target_type ${TARGET} TYPE)
    if (NOT target_type STREQUAL "STATIC_LIBRARY")
        return()
    endif()
    get_target_property(IMPORTED ${TARGET} IMPORTED)
    list(APPEND TARGET_DEPENDENCIES ${TARGET})
    if (IMPORTED)
        get_target_property(LIBS ${TARGET} INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
    else()
        get_target_property(LIBS ${TARGET} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    endif()
    foreach(LIB ${LIBS})
        if (TARGET ${LIB})
            list(FIND TARGET_DEPENDENCIES ${LIB} VISITED)
            if (${VISITED} EQUAL -1)
                get_dependencies(${LIB})
            endif()
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set(TARGET_DEPENDENCIES ${TARGET_DEPENDENCIES} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

function(merge_libraries target destination)
    get_dependencies(${target})

    list(TRANSFORM TARGET_DEPENDENCIES PREPEND "$<TARGET_FILE:")
    list(TRANSFORM TARGET_DEPENDENCIES APPEND ">")
            
    add_custom_target(Merge${target}Libraries
        COMMAND libtool -static -o ${destination} "$<GENEX_EVAL:$<JOIN:${TARGET_DEPENDENCIES}, >>"
        COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
        DEPENDS ${target})
endfunction()

Output:
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /path/to/lib1.a /path/to/lib2.a /path/to/lib3.a ... (File name too long)

EDIT:
Adding context to our constraints: the library we're building will later be linked by some C# and Swift applications. AFAIK we can use cmake and dynamic libraries for C#, but Swift/C++ interop requires a static library embedded in a xcframework, and that is the reason why we need to build it as a static library.
As already stated in the comments, the dependencies are c++ projects built together with our library using cmake FetchContent module.

Is this library used as a part of another project using cmake, or searched for  by another project using cmake?

not necessarily. It is used in different contexts and most of them do not use cmake, that is the main reason why we want to merge all the dependencies

ok, thanks for the clarification. The other question are the other libraries built as a part of your project or not?

it's a bunch of third party libraries that are built by FetchContent. I can change the way they are built (e.g. ExternalProject, prebuilt and passed via pkg-config) if that helps

It turns out I almost had it right, but there was an issue in the generator expression in the custom target.
As suggested here, I had to change the whitespace with $<SEMICOLON>
So the add_custom_target becomes
add_custom_target(Merge${target}Libraries
        COMMAND libtool -static -o ${destination} "$<GENEX_EVAL:$<JOIN:${TARGET_DEPENDENCIES},$<SEMICOLON>>>"
        COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
        DEPENDS ${target})

